# MySQL error when creating foreign key with Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

I have a Laravel application set up and I'm using [Sentry 2](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry) for user authentication. I have a model called `Post` along with the default sentry `User` table. I would like to have a user to have many posts, and a post to belong to a user. To reflect this in my database schema, I need to create a foreign key constraint between `posts` and `users`.

The migration that I've written is the following:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('user_id')->after('id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

After running it with `php artisan migrate`, I get a MySQL error in the command prompt:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table 'blog.dev.#sql-3bb_2d' (errno: 150) (SQL:
>   alter table `posts` add constraint posts_user_id_foreign
>   foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

At first I thought this error occurred because the primary key column in `users` is defined differently than my foreign key column `user_id`, however they're both defined as `int(10)`.

From Google I learned that this error might be caused by the two column definitions being different, however this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The foreign key should already be in database, therefore I suggest to take two steps. Also I suggest to make the column `user_id` unsigned:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('user_id')->after('id')->nullable()->unsigned();
    });

    Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved with

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

before first migration and

```
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

in last migration

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3dan.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->after('id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```