# Error in adding foreign key in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am beginner in laravel. I am having problem in adding foreign key in laravel. I tried but I can't find the error.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table laravel_home1

#sql-4b8_2a (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

(SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint
     `posts_comment_id_foreign` foreign key (`comment_id`) references
      `comments` (`id`))
```

post table migration code

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('content');       
        $table->integer('comment_id')->unsigned();
    });

    Schema::table('posts', function ($table) {
        $table->foreign('comment_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('comments');
    });
}
```

comments table migration code

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('comment');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('comments');
}
```

Comment: Have you already migrated your comments table?

Comment: If `comments` table is created before `posts`, please also share `comments` table migration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error when creating foreign key with Laravel migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122497/mysql-error-when-creating-foreign-key-with-laravel-migration)

Comment: Looks like you are creating first the table post, and comments table don't exist.

Comment: Also check if the field are the same type.

Comment: I created two tables first, bro.

Comment: be sure that the comment table already exist in the database

Comment: Put everything inside of `create` instead of the two seperate `create` and `table` functions, this might work.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with adding foreign key in laravel come with 3 reasons:

1. You have already done some rollbacks or migrated the same migration file multiple times and they are saved in cache and thus causing the problem
2. You forgot to put `->unsigned();` at the end of that index.
3. The table with primary key which is later used elsewhere as a foreign key is not migrated previously.

Either way try to put `->unsigned();` at the end like this

```
$table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items');
```

and then run `composer dump-autoload`

and then `php artisan migrate`

and this should work!

#### UPDATE

I have found what is wrong with your migration:

Replace this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('content');       
        $table->integer('comment_id')->unsigned();
    });

    Schema::table('posts', function ($table) {
        $table->foreign('comment_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('comments');
    });
}
```

With this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('content');       
        $table->integer('comment_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('comment_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('comments');
    });

}
```